# -[UIPickerView setFrame:]: invalid height value 200.0 pinned to 180.0

Tags: ipad, uipickerview

-[UIPickerView setFrame:]: invalid height value 200.0 pinned to 180.0 
i got this error in nslog. but i do not care about it .
any crash is possible in future ? . my coding is

```
    pickerviewdropdown.Dropoption    = [[Utility getSizeValues] mutableCopy];
        [pickerviewdropdown.pickerview reloadAllComponents];

        subOptionPopOver            = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:pickerviewdropdown];
        [subOptionPopOver setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(200, 200)];

        [subOptionPopOver presentPopoverFromRect:[sender bounds]
                                          inView:sender
                        permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                        animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 2):

Its obvious that you are setting the height to 200 when it should be 180.  There will not be a crash but I suggest you change your code to CGSizeMake(200, 180) so you don't keep getting that error.

Comment: hai sir i am using IBOutlet pickerview so wher i put those code and i am using uipicker view in separate view controller that view controler have only one uipickerview i will call it so many view controllers

Comment: Not really sure what you said but you cant really change a standard pickerviews height.

Comment: @property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerview;
 this is my coding sir why i need those cgsizemake

Comment: i used here non programatic picker view